# Interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

In order to serve PDF-files to clients the following request is sent to a php file which encodes the pdf to base64 server side and sends it back to the client where it is added to an iframe:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "get-base64-pdf.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {sessionid : sessionid},
    dataType: "text"
});

request.done(function(msg){
    $('#iframe').attr("src", "data:application/pdf;base64," + msg);
});
```

The script works but an error message from jquery (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4) turns up in the console:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "data:application/pdf;base64,

followed by the entire pdf in base64. I'm guessing this occurs because the data type is set to "text" but it will not work if changed to "application/pdf". Does anyone know if there is a way to either fix the issue or suppress the warning in the console?

EDIT

The php-script serves the base64 like so:

```
    $b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$Report")));

    if($b64Doc){
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        echo $b64Doc;
    } else {
        echo -1;
    }
```

Comment: Nearly a year later and I have a similar problem where an iframe on my page is to load PDF files to view. Chrome throws a warning in the console each time a new PDF is loaded. I don't see a real problem here, as the PDF files all load just fine, and can be viewed in all tested browsers, but it's something for which an explanation is desirable.